# Admin form using same Action Method for both?

Tags: magento-1.7, forms, adminform, admin-controller

Magento 1.7

In the Admin Panel under System-->Permissions-->Users

When I click on a User OR "Add New User" and I right click and inspect element I see the following for both:
[image]

They both share the same Action Url which doesn't make sense shouldn't me clicking on a User have a form with an action of **http://makeyourjewel.com/index.php/power/permissions_user/edit/** instead?

This is driving me insane because I don't know where to change this.  This code has been like this since I started working and I'm currently looking at Magento default base files to compare, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it is supposed to look.
The actual save is done in a separate actions.
One action does not respond differently depending on the verb you are using (get or post).
The add / edit form is displayed on the `new` or `edit` action, but it's the same form. The only difference is that on edit mode you have a hidden input with a non empty value (the id of the edited entity).

But in both add and edit, the actual save is done in a `save` action that is neither `new` or `edit`.
The difference is made based on the value of the hidden input value I mentioned above.

Comment: What's weird is I noticed that both forms come in as Post and go to the saveAction Method.  There is this line of code "$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');" but I echo the $id and its empty or null for both creating a user and editing a user so it is never true to exist?

Comment: I see that I am a fool. I was looking through my git history and in the Main.php that creates the form I changed $model->getUserId() to $user_id so it didn't know what I was talking about.  Thanks your comment actually helped me look more in the right direction.